# visual studio creating vb windows form in c++ project?

Tags: c++, vb.net, winforms, vba, visual-studio

Is it possible to create visual basic(vb) windows form in c++ project in visual studio? and how?

thanks before.

btw, I'm using visual studio community 2015

Comment: Why do you think you want do do that?

Comment: Semmes like a [XY-Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @VincentG : cause I don't find a certain codes for C++/CLI, but I find it for VB codes in internet

Answer (score 1):

No.  In C++ projects you use C++ and in VB projects you use VB.

Comment: Thanks for answering